# how to store old value and new value in same Nsmutablearray in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uitextfield, nsarray

hi i am new in `iOS` developer.

i have  `UITableView` and `UITextField`. I set some different value in textfield and each textfield's value store in `NSmutablearray` than i display this array in next screen. Displayed array value is perfect.
But my problem is when i switch back to the `UITableView` screen and than again set new value in `UITextField` and these `UITextField` value store in `NSmutablearray` .but problem is new value is override to old value. but i want both value store in `NSArray`.

here my screen shot

[image] [image]

summaryvc display perfect data.but when i back to the screen and select other item than click the placeorder.but problem is we cant get old selected item in summary screen.

here is button action code to store the array in Nsuserdefault. global.filteredArray is my nsmutablearray.dic value is my dictionary.

this is my array value

```
{
        counts = 1;
        "m_drycleaning_price" = 12;
        "m_id" = 3;
        "m_imagename" = d;
        "m_iron_price" = 16;
        "m_name" = "Coat(Man)";
        "m_wash_price" = 14;
        "m_washiron_price" = 13;
        total = 12;
    }









AppDelegate *myAppDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
                             [myAppDelegate.arrayCounts  addObject:dictValues];
myAppDelegate.arrayCounts[indexPath.row][@"counts"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)value];
    myAppDelegate.arrayCounts[indexPath.row][@"total"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)y];


    - (IBAction)placeorder:(id)sender
         {
            NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

            [userDefaults setObject:global.filteredArray forKey:@"def_orderarraylist"];

            NSMutableArray *qualifiersArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[userDefaults objectForKey:@"def_orderarraylist"]];

        NSLog(@"qualifier array=%@",qualifiersArray);

        [userDefaults synchronize];

        }
```

please help!

Comment: Have u tried to store with nsuserdefaults?

Comment: as uma said, you have to store your nsarray into nsuserdefaults. then only you will get all the values. When you coming back to the first screen, the array will be initialized. so you didnt get the old data.

Comment: @uma yaa i will try nsuserdefault but not solve problem.

Comment: @Signare yaa i wll not get old data

Comment: any new datatype to hold old and new value pls tell me

Comment: You need to create new array for old data when you change value of existing array member that before you just add into the separate array called as a `oldArray`.

Comment: better to share your code if possible

Comment: @DarjiJigar if you have code then upload it

Comment: @VvkAghera code is bro so complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You must declare your array on class rather than on your method and you'll be fine.

You could do something like:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

OR

Use a `NSUserDefaults` and it will stay until the app is deleted.

If you have two screens you could simply pass the array reference to your second screen if you want to edit your array from there.

**FirstViewController:**

Setup your array:

```
SecondViewController *svc= [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
svc.firstViewArray=secondViewArray;
```

**SecondViewController:**

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *secondViewArray;
```

Comment: NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];                 [userDefaults setObject:myAppDelegate.arrayCounts forKey:@"finalarray"];      [userDefaults synchronize];

Comment: Ok, if you're using NSUserDefaults then you could simply get back your array, set new values and store it back to NSUserDefaults as suggested by user Uma

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are using global array to store data to NSUserDefaults. While doing this you need to make sure this points:

1. First thing you need to do is while Adding data to global array, First take previous data from NSUserDefaults & add it to global array.
2. You need to make sure every time while you add new data to global array you have added previous data to global array from NSUserDefaults
3. One more thing you need to make sure it global array should be NSMutable array & while you initialize this array, after that Add previous values from NSUserDefaults in it.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: how to add previoud data in global array.

Comment: @DarjiJigar similar like you getting value in qualifiersArray in PlaceOrder method from NSUserDefaults